# How to cover Boolean method in Test Class?

Tags: unit-test

Here is the Code.

```
public with sharing class page1
{    
   @TestVisible private integer totalRecs = 0;     
   @TestVisible private integer index = 0;
    public integer blockSize = 5;         

    public page1(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        totalRecs = [select count() from Account where name!= null limit 10];        
    }    

    public List<Account> getaccounts() 
    {
        List<Account> accs = Database.Query('SELECT name, site, Phone, Website, Fax, AccountNumber, Rating FROM Account LIMIT :blockSize OFFSET :index');
        System.debug('Values are ' + accs);
        return accs;
    }    

    public void beginning()
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    public void previous()
    {
        index = index - blockSize;
    }

    public void next()
    {
        index = index + blockSize;
    }

    public void end()
    {
        index = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,blockSize);
    }        

    public boolean getprev()
    {
        if(index == 0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }  

    public boolean getnxt()
    {
        if((index + blockSize) > totalRecs)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }         
}
```

**Not able to cover else statement in Boolean method**

Comment: Just call those methods like `page1 obj = new page1(); obj.getprev();`

Comment: Yeah Ratan. I Did the same but its not cover else part of those methods

Comment: again set the `obj.index =1` then again call `obj.getprev();` it will cover the else part as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `page1 obj = new page1(); obj.getprev();` `getprev` method

Also for else part you need to set index `obj.index =1` then again call `obj.getprev();` it will cover the else part as well

fOR checking put some system.assertequals to check expected value